# IIF Statement if a value is zero, skip this and display next value

Tags: reporting-services, expression, iif

I have the following dataset from my query:

[image]

Each Court will have four months of Counts, one for each month. I need it to display one row for each Court and count for each month. Grouping by Court will not work because it renders a total for the four counts.

Looking for an IIF statement to accomplish this. Or another solution.

Thanks for any feedback.

Regards,
jer

Comment: Show your data that we can consume easily and not as pictures.. no one likes typing in sample data!

Comment: On second thought.. why not group by courtame and Max of the value you have in the month column? I'd do this in SQL or whatever your data source is and just display the results here.

Comment: +1 for @Harry suggestion. SQL is the best place to do this especially if there is a lot of data to aggregate but you could stay in SSRS to do this. A simple group by courtname and then value expression would be `=MAX(Fields!myMonthCountColumn.Value)`

Comment: Thanks, Harry and Alan Schofield. I was grouping within SQL already but stayed in SSRS. Did a group on CourtName, added expression to each month's cell as suggested and all is good.